# chrome remote desktop on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, chromium, remote

I'm trying to use chrome remote desktop on ubuntu 22.04 with chromium browser
following the procedure I install the application (version 108.0.5359.33) but, after installation, on the browser page it keeps asking to accept and install, while it should advance to "choose a name" step
already tryed to remove and reinstall CRD app, also by terminal
I'm a very basic user so very few knowledge of ubuntu system

this should show correct installation of CRD:

*fii@fii-HP-Laptop:~$ apt-cache policy chrome-remote-desktop
chrome-remote-desktop:
Installed: 108.0.5359.33
Candidate:  108.0.5359.33
Version table:
*** 108.0.5359.33 500
500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status*

thanks for any advice